# REST Api Tracking Unique Page Views

Tags: php, rest, api, google-analytics, redis

I am developing a PHP REST api using Api Platform for my website where users can post 'Reviews' (similar to articles).I want to track unique page views for this articles so I can later sort by most viewed reviews and display them.

I have read a lot of solutions online and I have implemented two of them: Google Analytics tracking and Redis + browser fingerprinting.

First, the Google Analytics tracking works quite well, I am using the 'ga:uniquePageviews' property with a filter for the page path to get using the Google PHP Api the unique page views. The only problem with this method is that some users use ad blockers and they block Google Analytics so no page view will be recorded for those people.

I have also implemented view tracking using Redis + browser fingerprinting (using fingerprintjs2) for anonymous users, and using the user id for logged in users. So for logged in users, if they have not visited the page in the last 30 minutes, a new unique view is added. This seems to work quite well.
The problem is with anonymous users. Currently, on the website side I am using fingerprintjs2 library to generate a browser fingerprint which is then passed to the REST api in a header and if that fingerprint did not visit the page in the last 30 minutes, then a new unique view is added. But because my REST api is going to be public (I plan on maybe also making a mobile app in the future), anyone can just put whatever then want in the fingerprint header and just keep changing it and a new unique view will be recorded and I am not sure how to fix this. Would allowing CORS only from my website domain fix this?But then what about the mobile app?

Right now I am inclined to think that using Google Analytics is the best way despite ad blockers, but the Redis approach just seems pretty cool to me and I would also like to get that working.

Here is a code example of what I am currently using for Redis:

```
public function addAndGetReviewViews(Request $request, $id)
{
    $viewsKey = 'pageviews-review-' . $id;
    $setKey = 'uniqueviews-review-' . $id;

    $user = $this->getUser();

    if ($user) {
        $userId = $user->getId();
    } else if ($request->headers->has('X-Anonymous-Fingerprint')) {
        $userId = base64_encode(
            substr($request->headers->get('X-Anonymous-Fingerprint'), 0, 32)
        );
    } else {
        // Only add views if user is logged in or has anonymous fingerprint
        return $this->redis->get($viewsKey) ?: 0;
    }

    $setExists = $this->redis->exists($setKey);

    if (!$this->redis->sismember($setKey, $userId)) {
        $this->redis->sadd($setKey, $userId);
        $this->redis->incr($viewsKey);
    }

    if (!$setExists) {
        $this->redis->expire($setKey, 1800);
    }

    return $this->redis->get($viewsKey);
}
```

Comment: So no one can provide any information to me about this?Some tips or just anything?

Comment: I would like to get some suggestions about this from some of you guys.